# angularjs style background-color binding not working in IE11

Tags: angularjs

getting empty `style` attribute in IE11 for the following binding:

`<a class="badge" style="background-color: {{colour}}">Some text</a>`

works fine in Chrome. Any pointers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed with ng-style:

`<a class="badge" ng-style="::{'background-color': colour}">Some text</a>`

Comment: Can you elaborate your answer by mentioning that `::` are used for one time binding. Users landing to this should know about it.